# HttpWebRequest login to facebook. Cookie not allowed

Tags: c#, facebook, cookies, c#-4.0, facebook-login

```
        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;

        string getUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
        string postData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}", "xxxxxx", "xxxx");
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
```

//recover cookies First request`

```
    getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); 
    getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
    getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
    getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

open connection and send the data

```
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); 
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I am getting a source with information that the cookies are not allowed

Comment: Facebook uses Tls 1.2. Set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` before anything else. You are not correctly managing your `CookieContainer()`. Create the container once with `CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();`, then assign it to your HttpWebRequest with `getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;` and re-assign it each time you make a new request. Then there's the postData...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there are can be 2 reasons.

1. When I run your code I got a message that my browser was too old. Maybe you're using the old user agent, cause your user agent string has Chrome 15 whereas the newest version is 60. So it's really old. Try to set it to newest one:

5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36

2. Cookies can be disallowed cause Facebook can require to accept cookies agreement before using them. Something like this:

[image]

So if you don't accept this you won't be able to use cookies.

It's just my guessing but maybe it will help you somehow.